# SVG text - total length changes depending on zoom

Tags: firefox, text, svg, opera

In SVG (for web-browsers), if i add a `<text>`-element and add some text to it the total rendered width of the text string will change depending on the scale of the text.

Lets say i add "*mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmA*" as text, then i want to draw a vertical line(or other exactly positioned element) intersecting the very last character. Works fine but if i zoom out the text will become shorter or longer and the line will not intersect the text in the right place anymore. The error can be as much as +/- 5 characters width which is unacceptable. The error is also unpredictable, 150% and 160% zoom can add 3 characters length while 155% is 2 charlengths shorter.

My zoom is implemented as a scale-transform on the root element of my canvas which is a `<g>`.
I have tried to multiply the font-size with 1000x and scale down equally on the zoom-transform and vice versa in case it was a floating point error but the result is the same.

I found the `textLength`-attribute[1] which is supposed to adjust the total length so the text always end where i choose but it only works in Webkit. Firefox and Opera seems to not care at all about this value (haven't tried in IE9 yet).

Is there any way to render text exactly positioned without resorting to homemade filling of font-outlines?

[1] http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextElementTextLengthAttribute

**Update**

Snippet of the structure i'm using

```
<svg>
<g transform="scale(1)">      <!--This is the root, i'm changing the scale of this element to zoom -->
    <g transform="scale(0.014)"> <!--This is a wrapper for multi-line text, scaling, other grouping etc -->
        <text font-size="1000" textLength="40000">ABDCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZÅÄÖabcdefghijklmnopqrstxyzåäö1234567890</text>
    </g>
</g>
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, since the webkit builds I have seem to fail on textLength ([w3c testcase](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObject/text-text-01-b.html)). Could you post your example?

Speaking for Opera we do support the 'textLength' attribute, as documented [here](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto27/svg/attributes/).

The other option you have is to use the [getBBox method](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) to find a good position for drawing your line, that should work in all the browsers.

Comment: Did another test with opera and it appears to be "almost" working there. If i set textLength the text will scale to almost hit the final location. For example 2x longer will look 2x longer but zooming in and out will still shift maybe +/-3 characters width. Build 1156. See example in update.

Comment: btw, the testcase you sent works fine in the latest user-version of Chrome.

Comment: Feel free to send a mail with a full testcase to www-svg@w3.org and we'll consider adding it to the w3c svg testsuite.